# All my Project that Has StoreProvider now not working

Tags: react-redux

[image]

I dont know What Happend Suddenly this issue start showing , But if I remove the provider my project start normally ,can you help me solve this issue please?

Comment: What are your versions of react, react-dom, react-redux and redux

Comment: do you mind to add code for that component where you added this provider?

Comment: "react": "^16.13.1",
    "react-dom": "^16.13.1",
    "react-redux@7.2.0

Comment: i wanted to add more images but  i cant this is my first question here ,but it seems that the error is not from the code that i added . when i remove the provider the project open without errors . i went back to my old project and the same problem appear even though they worked fine couple days back. I am a beginner in the react world.